# Flex: TextFlow ignores whitespaces

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flex-spark, richeditabletext

i'm trying to add whitespaces in front of my text, but flex removes all but one whitespace from the text. So i can't format the text.

Here is the specified line:

```
<s:p> •  Lorem</s:p>
<s:p>    ipsulum</s:p>
```

Here its shown correctly but when running the swf it reduces the whitespaces of the second line. Of course i tried to use CDATA but this didn't work too.

Cheers
Felix

Comment: Perhaps a bit besides the question, but I noticed you seem to try to create a list. There's a specific element for that, you know: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7ff6.html

Comment: Stupid question : have you tried using HTML non-breaking spaces "&nbsp;" ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
my_textFlow.whiteSpaceCollapse = WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE;
```

Check the [TextFlow Adobe reference for whiteSpaceCollapse for FlowElement](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/FlowElement.html#whiteSpaceCollapse).

Comment: This solves the whitespace issue, but i had to remove all formatting with paragraph tags and ALL other whitespaces which are not used.

Answer (score 1):

Try using unicode character for non breaking space "\u00A0".